# How to use the @jit(target='cuda') line for GPU usage

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to speed up my code by using my GPU, and I found the `@jit(target='cuda')` line using numba pack to enable the use of GPU, but I was wondering if the `@jit(target='cuda')` only makes the immediate function under it run using the GPU or if it would make the whole code run on the GPU?
Please tell me which way I should have the line in my code:
1.

```
@jit(target='cuda')
def func1():
    for x in range(100):
        pass


# then reuse the line


@jit(target='cuda')
def func2():
    for x in range(100):
        pass
```

or should I do this:

```
# only use the line once
@jit(target='cuda')
def func1():
    for x in range(100):
        pass


def func2():
    for x in range(100):
        pass
```

If I have some misunderstandings about how to use numba or jit, please do tell me, I still have a lot to learn about computer sciences and python.

Comment: This seems like the kind of information that would be found in the documentation, no?

Comment: It is a function decorator.  It only makes the function that it is decorating run on the GPU.  It appears before a `def` and it includes everything included by that `def`